# Container Div not encapsulating content

Tags: html, css, containers

Just started CSS and HTML and I'm a bit puzzled. Unless I include `position:fixed` border of the div container, which is the main container that houses everything, the div is stuck at the top of everything and won't auto height to surround all the content inside of it.

[Here's what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Af6dm.png)

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body> 
<div id="container">

<div id="header">
        <header> 
            <nav>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="header">Ben</li> 
                    <li class="nav"><a href="#">About me</a></li> 
                    <li class="nav"><a href="uni.html">University Units</a></li>
                    <li class="nav" style="border-right: none;"><a href="#">Soft Skills</a><!-- inline style to remove border right --></li> 
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header><!-- closes header -->
</div><!--Closes header -->



<div id="content">
    <h1>University Units</h1> <!-- content header -->

    <article>

    <h2>Introduction to Web Design</h2>

    This unit provides an introduction to the fundamental principles and mathematics underpinning the design and construction of computer systems, including:
    <ul class="csf">
        <li>Digital Logic and Boolean Algebra: digital logic gates and circuits, Karnaugh maps, use of a digital logic circuit simulator, components of a CPU, processor model, Fetch execute cycle, hardware interrupts</li>
        <li>Assembly Language Programming: relationship between high level languages and assembler, instruction sets, registers, debugging</li>
        <li>Discrete Mathematics: matrices and vectors, matrices as linear transforms</li>
        <li>Functions: definition, properties</li>
        <li>Sets: subsets, set algebra</li>
        <li>Logic: propositions, predicates, propositional algebra, proof of simple results</li>
    </ul>

    <h2>Programming</h2>
    An introduction to the use of information systems in organisations which will show you how to develop key systems analysis techniques to be applied to information systems built on a commercial RDBMS. You will also develop essential communication skills. You will examine business activities supported by information systems including case studies and examples, e-commerce, management information, privacy. Systems analysis and design techniques: use cases, UML. Database management systems and database design: ERDs, normalisation, SQL. Communication and teamwork skills.

    <br><br>

    Details of other units continued on the <a href="uni2.htm">next page</a>


    </article>





</div><!-- Closes content -->


</div><!-- Closes container -->

</body>

</html>
```

And CSS (Which is probably a mess):

```
 /* main */

#container{
    position: fixed; 
    width: 75%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 25px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

#header{
    position: fixed;
    width: 75%;
    float: left;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}


nav{
    float: top;
}

li.nav{
    display: inline;
    font-family: roboto;
    text-decoration:none;   
    color: black;
    border-right: 2px solid #7c7b7c;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

li.header{
    display: inline;
    font-size: 200%;
    font-family: bebas;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border-right: 3px solid black;
}

header a:link{
    text-decoration: none;

    font-size: 200%;
    color: black;
}


ul.nav{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#content{
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 80px;
}

#content article{
    font-family: roboto;
    padding-right: 5px;
    float: left;
}

#content a:link{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    color: blue;
}

#content a:visted{
    color:purple;
}

#content h1{
    font-family: roboto;
}

#content h2{
    font-family: roboto;
}

/* fonts */

@font-face{
    font-family: bebas;
    src: url(bebas.otf);
}

@font-face{
    font-family: roboto;
    src: url(roboto.ttf);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the position on the container div and the header div to absolute...as seen below

```css
/* main */

#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 75%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 25px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
#header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 75%;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}
nav {
  float: top;
}
li.nav {
  display: inline;
  font-family: roboto;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  border-right: 2px solid #7c7b7c;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
li.header {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 200%;
  font-family: bebas;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
}
header a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 200%;
  color: black;
}
ul.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#content {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 80px;
}
#content article {
  font-family: roboto;
  padding-right: 5px;
  float: left;
}
#content a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 100%;
  color: blue;
}
#content a:visted {
  color: purple;
}
#content h1 {
  font-family: roboto;
}
#content h2 {
  font-family: roboto;
}
/* fonts */

@font-face{

font-family:bebas;
 src:url(bebas.otf);

}
@font-face{

font-family:roboto;
 src:url(roboto.ttf);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">

    <div id="header">
      <header>
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav">
            <li class="header">Ben</li>
            <li class="nav"><a href="#">About me</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav"><a href="uni.html">University Units</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav" style="border-right: none;"><a href="#">Soft Skills</a>
              <!-- inline style to remove border right -->
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <!-- closes header -->
    </div>
    <!--Closes header -->



    <div id="content">
      <h1>University Units</h1> 
      <!-- content header -->

      <article>

        <h2>Introduction to Web Design</h2>
        This unit provides an introduction to the fundamental principles and mathematics underpinning the design and construction of computer systems, including:
        <ul class="csf">
          <li>Digital Logic and Boolean Algebra: digital logic gates and circuits, Karnaugh maps, use of a digital logic circuit simulator, components of a CPU, processor model, Fetch execute cycle, hardware interrupts</li>
          <li>Assembly Language Programming: relationship between high level languages and assembler, instruction sets, registers, debugging</li>
          <li>Discrete Mathematics: matrices and vectors, matrices as linear transforms</li>
          <li>Functions: definition, properties</li>
          <li>Sets: subsets, set algebra</li>
          <li>Logic: propositions, predicates, propositional algebra, proof of simple results</li>
        </ul>

        <h2>Programming</h2>
        An introduction to the use of information systems in organisations which will show you how to develop key systems analysis techniques to be applied to information systems built on a commercial RDBMS. You will also develop essential communication skills.
        You will examine business activities supported by information systems including case studies and examples, e-commerce, management information, privacy. Systems analysis and design techniques: use cases, UML. Database management systems and database
        design: ERDs, normalisation, SQL. Communication and teamwork skills.

        <br>
        <br>Details of other units continued on the <a href="uni2.htm">next page</a>


      </article>





    </div>
    <!-- Closes content -->


  </div>
  <!-- Closes container -->

</body>

</html>
```